# Sitecore Query returns null when using attributes

Tags: xpath, sitecore, sitecore6

We have a sitecore support ticket open for this issue, but I hope I could get someone else that's experienced this issue also.

Here is the output from my immediate window while debugging my sitecore 6.6 instance:

```
?db.SelectSingleItem("/sitecore/content/Www/Data/Recruiting/Metadata/Companies/00000001/*[@@name='0000001873']")
null
?db.SelectSingleItem("/sitecore/content/Www/Data/Recruiting/Metadata/Companies/00000001/*")
0000001873 (en#1@web), id: {1848E256-E7C2-4BFC-9AF7-72EE14E37C82}
Database: "web"
Id: "{1848E256-E7C2-4BFC-9AF7-72EE14E37C82}"
Language: "en"
Name: "0000001873"
Version: "1"
```

Basically when I run either SelectSingleItem or GetItem and include any attribute (@@id or @@name), I get null returned.  However, if I remove the filtering attribute I do get a result set.   Notice that the result set I get without the filter, is the first item in the list, is also the item I'm searching for with the @@name attribute.

I get this result ONLY in code.  Using xPath designer I get a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue and it ended up being a folder whose name started with the number zero. I chalked it up as a potential issue with the way Sitecore parses queries and didn't look into it much further. Try escaping the folder name like so:

```
/sitecore/content/Www/Data/Recruiting/Metadata/Companies/#00000001#/*[@@name='0000001873']
```

Comment: This is exactly what Sitecore support eventually said and worked for the query above.  My ultimate issue however was that I was using GetItem instead of SelectSingleItem, since the path included an attribute.